# What are my options when creating a link between an application and a browser?

Tags: web-services

At the moment I'm using PHP to do all the work but I would like to dedicate a server to a process and want to get the result of this process (Generated files and images).

I have some experience with C# and found some information about wcf/rest web services but I'm not completely sure what the way to go is and what other options there are and which are the least server intensive when generating files and sending them back to the client while in the meantime logging information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options. You could still use PHP to generate a JSON output that could be consumed by an AJAX front-end (like Angular JS for instance). That way your learning curve will be faster and you'll be using one of the very best front-end frameworks to date.

Comment: I would like to use multithreading and PHP doesn't natively support this so I don't want to use PHP preferrably.

Comment: Then you should consider Node JS. It works great with Angular JS and JSON as it's basically server-side Javascript.